# How to do versioning of shared library?

Tags: linux, shared-libraries

Windows provides the resource file for version information for an application and DLL. The resource file includes information like version, copyright and manufacturer.

We have a shared library and would like to add version information.

How can we do it on Linux with a shared library?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The short version is that you do this via the [soname](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soname) of the library. Read chapter 3 at http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/shared-libraries.html as well as chapter 3.3 ABI Versioning at http://www.akkadia.org/drepper/dsohowto.pdf

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I was redirected from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42314722/multiple-versions-of-same-the-same-library-in-ld-library-path) but I still don't understand how one program can understand which library version to use. I want that one program use one version and another the new version.

Comment: One comment on the [Program-Library-HOWTO](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/shared-libraries.html): if you are writting receipt for install in makefile, you should do nothing other than generating & copying files into destination dir. so do not call ldconfig in receipt, just create symbolic link file with soname to realname (for your bin-package) and create linkname to soname (for your dev-package), and installer can call ldconfig by themselves after "make install" if they install the library into non-standard location. because "make install" may be invoked for cross-compiling

Answer (score 5):

The best way to handle this is using libtool, which does the versioning for you.

Essentially, version information is not (or not primarily, don't know from my head) encoded in the library itself, but rather in its filename. Version numbers are normally given in three-dot format, with the major number increasing for each break in downward ABI compatibility, the middle for breaks in upward ABI compatibility, and the minor for patches that did not change the ABI.

Like qdot noted, symlinks in the lib directory provide the essential versioning. There is a symlink without a version number (libfoo.so) for the currently installed development headers, a symlink with a major number for each installed major version (libfoo.so.1) and a real file with the full version number. Normally, programs are linked to use libfoo.so.1 at runtime so that multiple major versions may coexist.

Comment: I agree that the libtool scheme seems to be the best. Your answer seems to be wrong on the order of digits. The correct order is `current[:revision[:age]]`. So the middle is for patches, the last one is the degree of backward compatibility. [libtools docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/libtool/manual/html_node/Updating-version-info.html)

Comment: You can play with the effects of `-version-info C:R:A` live at https://verbump.de/ .

Answer (score 4):

Linux uses the following strategy - you (the system maintainer) provide symlinks from a 'specific' shared library file, like this:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    16 2011-09-22 14:36 libieee1284.so -> libieee1284.so.3
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    20 2011-09-22 14:36 libieee1284.so.3 -> libieee1284.so.3.2.2
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 46576 2011-07-27 13:08 libieee1284.so.3.2.2
```

This way, developers can link either against -lieee1284 (any version ABI), or libieee1284.so.3 or even to the specific release and patch version (3.2.2)

Comment: Note that  "-lieee1284" links to whatever the libieee1284.so points to at linking time, not runtime. libieee1284.so likely has a soname of libieee1284.so.3 , and that's the name that will be embedded in the executable, and searched for during runtime.