# Multiple versions of same the same library in LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Tags: linux, environment-variables, shared-libraries

Let's suppose I need two shared library `a.so` and `b.so` . Now, both `a.so` and `b.so` are installed in `/usr/local/lib`. So I simply need to `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. So far so good.

Now, let's suppose that I need another version of `a.so` which is installed in `~/testing/lib`. If I do `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=~/testing/lib` combined with the previous `export`, which version of `a.so` is going to be used? Note that I can't avoid the first export since I need `b.so` (which is present only in the first path).

Comment: Also related: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/475/how-do-so-shared-object-numbers-work

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ thanks for your comment, but I still don't understand how versioning works. Should I call `~/testing/lib/a.so.1`? And I don't understand how one application can use `/usr/local/lib/a.so` and how another can use `~/testing/lib/a.so`?